# How do I override a method of an Abstract Inner Class?

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class, javac, inner-classes

My codes are:

**core/Base.java**

```
package core;
public class Base {
    public abstract class AbstractInner {
        abstract void run();
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
class Test extends core.Base {
    class Inner extends AbstractInner {
        void run() {}
    }
}
```

javac complains like the following;

```
shell> javac -cp . Test.java 
Test.java:2: Test.Inner is not abstract and does not override abstract method run() in core.Base.AbstractInner
    class Inner extends AbstractInner {
    ^
```

What is my mistake?

If Base is in the same package as Test, compile is successful. I don't know why.

Comment: @override annotation is missing... I could be wrong tho I'm new to java as well.

Comment: @override annotation does not solve this problem. you can try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some non-intuitive rules governing overridibility of package-private members.  Essentially, you can override a package-private method if the overriding class is in the same package.  If it's not, it does not have visibility to *see* `AbstractInner`'s declaration of `run()` and so can't override it.  Instead you are declaring a new method with the same signature.

If you make `run()` protected (or public) in `AbstractInner` (and thus in `Inner` as well) instead of using the default visibility, it will work as intended.

Recall that only in interfaces are declared methods implicitly `public`.  In abstract classes, they are implicitly package-private.